# How send entire row in an email based on a specific date in cell, Send email 1 week before and 1 day before

Tags: email, google-sheets

I am new to google sheets. I have a spreadsheet where I record all exams that will be taking place. I manually send emails to the team one week before the exam date and also 1 day before. In the email I include the exam details (basically one row).

I am looking for a way to automatically send emails 1 week and 1 day before each exam date to the whole team. Each exam will be on different sheets for example all GCSE Maths Exam will be on one sheet and all
Mathematics will be on another

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have read some forums however i cant work out how to send 1 week and 1 day before a specific date.

The link to my spreadsheet is below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_UtQCN5vXvGOtLD15abKbKKArm3TbuVucHrfnAL7Ho/edit?usp=sharing

I dont have much code as this is new to me however I am trying to understand.

```
function CustomEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:I100");
  var UserData = range.getValues();

  for (i in UserData) {
    var row = UserData[i];
    var CentreNumber = row[0];
    var Exam = row[1];
    var ExamDate = row[4];
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[8], "mrmtm2016@gmail.com", "Hello Colleague" + CentreNumber + ", This is a reminder of the scheduled Exam " + Exam);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to your Google Apps Project. 
Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, for example every day between 3am and 4am.

Then you would set your CustomEmail function as the function to be run every day. 
[Step by step instructions on how to add a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Inside your CustomEmail, you will have to change your for loop. You need to compare every ExamDate with today's date and send an email if there is a difference of 1 day or 1 week.

Today's date is calculated as `Date.now()`, but I don't know how ExamDates are represented in your sheets. Look up how to convert both today's date and the ExamDate to the same representation.

[Here's how you do calculations with dates in javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Hi there,Thank you for your answer, i will look into this. I appreciate your time, thank you.